Proper dash with XeLaTeX / Lucida Calligraphy
When using the font Lucida Calligraphy with XeLaTeX the dashes do not work correctly: -- gives two small dashes instead of a longer one. How can I repair that?
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\newfontfamily\headingfont{Lucida Calligraphy}
\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\headingfont\filcenter}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\headingfont}
\begin{document}
\section*{Hello-World}
\section*{Hello--World}
\section*{Hello---World}
\end{document}


unrelated but don't use xltxtra these days, just use fontspec directly.

titlesec is not compatible with scrartcl.

The Ligatures=TeX feature is only added by default to fonts declared with \setmainfont, \setsansfont. TeX ligatures aren't enabled with fonts declared with \newfontfamily unless you add them.
You can use the characters directly:
Or can explicitly specify that the TeX ligatures should apply via [Ligatures=TeX]

\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Lucida Calligraphy}
\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\headingfont\filcenter}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\headingfont}
\begin{document}
\section*{Hello-World}
\section*{Hello--World}
\section*{Hello---World}
\section*{Hello–World}
\section*{Hello—World}


\end{document}


Did you try \newfontfamily\headingfont{Lucida Calligraphy}[Ligatures=TeX]?

@egreg well mostly I was wondering why the default tex ligature didn't apply, but I'll add a note

oh is it just setmainfont and friends that default tex ligatures,...

@egreg yes that's even documented:-)

@rallg yes certainly I thought of mentioning with the funky W you need to adjust the space, but I thought I'd keep to the issue at hand,
